# Setting group-level covariate in RSiena

Tags: r, social-networking, network-analysis

I'm having a terrible time trying to set a group-level variable in RSiena. My data are complicated, but I'm modeling 8 classrooms of 24 students over six periods. I am modeling how teacher behavior and student personality influence friendships. I am using a measure of teacher behavior as a group-level covariate.

The code is complicated enough that it really isn't feasible to provide a minimal reproducible example. But, I've uploaded data objects and linked them below so the code can be run.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1FXf3DWfIE23IkEChMoulXjzqxRy7HYko?usp=sharing

I'm attempting to use sienaBayes from the multiSiena package. The problem I'm having is that I get the following error when testing time homogeneity.

> TimeTest constructed a null hypothesis with 3 estimated parameters
> and 117 dummy variables to be tested.
> However, there are 40 linear dependencies between these.

> This may be because some of the parameters are already
> interactions with time dummies or other time variables.
> Automatic discovery of dependencies yielded the exclusion of effects
> Error in row(fitEffects)[baseInFit, drop = FALSE][extraExclusions, drop = FALSE][,  :
> incorrect number of dimensions

Installing multiSiena requires a windows machine and is kind of a chore, but you can get through this part just using RSiena:

```
library(multiSiena) #optional
library(RSiena)

dataObjList <- list()
for(z in 1:8){
  
  currentArray <- sienaDependent(friendshipObjectArrayList[[z]])
  extraversion <- coCovar((attribute_list[[z]]$extra))
  neuroticism <- coCovar((attribute_list[[z]]$neur))
  teacherBehave <- coCovar(rep(((teacher_df[z, ]$behavior)), 24))
  gender <- coCovar(attribute_list[[z]]$gender)

  dataObjList[[z]] <- sienaDataCreate(currentArray, extraversion, teacherBehave, 
                                      neuroticism, gender)
}

sienaObjList <- sienaGroupCreate(dataObjList)

testAlgo <- sienaAlgorithmCreate(projname = NULL,
                                 n3=500)

##Effects
basicEffects <- getEffects(sienaObjList, nintn = 200)


basicEffects <- setEffect(basicEffects, inPop)
basicEffects <- setEffect(basicEffects, transTrip)
basicEffects <- setEffect(basicEffects, outAct)
basicEffects <- setEffect(basicEffects, cycle3)
basicEffects <- setEffect(basicEffects, transTies)
basicEffects <- setEffect(basicEffects, simX,
                          interaction1 = "extraversion")
basicEffects <- setEffect(basicEffects, egoSqX,
                          interaction1 = "extraversion")

basicEffects <- setEffect(basicEffects, inPopX,
                          interaction1 = c("neuroticism"))

##group-level effect
basicEffects <- includeEffects(basicEffects, egoX, name = "currentArray",
                               interaction1 = "teacherBehave")


##Model
testAns <- siena07(testAlgo, data = sienaObjList, effects = basicEffects,
                   useCluster = TRUE, nbrNodes = 4)

timeAns <- summary(sienaTimeTest(testAns))
```

I then go on to run sienaBayes, but I need the homogeneity tests for that analysis to be meaningful.

Thanks for any help you're able to offer. I've been banging my head against this and consulted every siena resource I can find. I can't find anything that I'm doing that's different from the scripts on the website. So, thoughts welcome and appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it took a while, but as expected, it's a simple answer: any dummies (including for group or time) need to be excluded from sienaTimeTest using the effects argument. When I used

```
timeAns <- summary(sienaTimeTest(testAns, effects = c(1:5))
```

it worked just fine.

What I'm finding odd, though, is that isn't true all the time. There are instances in the RscriptMultipleGroups.R tutorial in which multigroup analyses are performed--sometimes with time dummies, sometimes not--and in which the effects argument is left out. sienaTimeTest runs without a problem.

If anyone can explain that discrepancy, it would be helpful. Either way, though, I hope this helpful to someone facing the same problem.